# Why all my debug buttons in IntelliJ are all grayed out

Tags: debug, intellij-idea

[I set a breakpoint and did the debug. The program stopped there, but all buttons above the red line were grayed out. I hope someone can tell me the reason and teach me how to restore it. Thank you.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q6afv.jpg)

[The entire code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IVVC8.jpg)

[My SDKs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sKX66.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

> Why all my debug buttons in IntelliJ are all grayed out

Because you are at the "Console" tab, not at the "Debugger" tab.